# 3D Polar Plot - griddata doesn't allow cubic interpolation, only linear which results in an "unsmooth" plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am plotting a 3D polar plot of field strength around an antenna. A sample of the data looks like this:

```
0.5  0  -22
0.5  0  -21
0.5  0  -22
0.5  0  -21
0.5  0  -22
0.5  0  -22
0.5  0  -22
0.5  0  -22
```

Where the 1st column is a radius from the antenna, the 2nd is an angle around the antenna and the 3rd is a dBm value of the field strength.

I have taken a number of samples at each point which are averaged by my script. 3 corresponding lists R, P and Z which contain the radius, the angle and the linear value for field strength at each unique point.

I want to plot a 3D polar plot of the values. And to do this I convert the R and P values from polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates X and Y.

```
# transform them to cartesian system 
X,Y = R*np.cos(P),R*np.sin(P)
```

I then use the following code to interpolate the data

```
xi = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),100)
yi = np.linspace(Y.min(),Y.max(),100)

zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')
```

Then I create a grid and plot the data as follows

```
xig, yig = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

surf = ax.plot_surface(xig, yig, zi,linewidth=0)
plt.show()
```

This creates the following plot

[image: Plot]

Is there a way to make the surface more smooth? Interpolating the data using griddata type=cubic does not work and just fills the matrix zi with "nan" values. Perhaps there is a better 3D alternative or I'm doing something wrong?

Using the suggested interp2d function has just resulted in zi being filled with nan values. I have used it in the following ways:

```
zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')
interp2d(xi, yi, zi, kind='cubic')
```

and

```
zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')
zi = interp2d(xi, yi, zi, kind='cubic')
```

Both of which gave the following error,

```
Warning:     No more knots can be added because the number of B-spline coefficients
already exceeds the number of data points m. Probably causes: either
s or m too small. (fp>s)
kx,ky=3,3 nx,ny=104,105 m=10000 fp=nan s=0.000000
```

I also tried

```
interp = interp2d(X,Y,Z,kind='cubic'); new_zi = interp(xi, yi)
```

This gave me a similar error:

```
Warning:     No more knots can be added because the number of B-spline coefficients
already exceeds the number of data points m. Probably causes: either
s or m too small. (fp>s)
kx,ky=3,3 nx,ny=14,15 m=104 fp=nan s=0.000000
```

although m is much smaller.

It looks like the problem is the s being 0 and fp=nan. What are these values?

Comment: You could make `xi` and `yi` coarser, and the run [`interp2d(xi, yi, zi, kind='cubic')`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) on a finer grid.

Comment: So instead of `xi = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),100)` recue the hundred to a smaller number?

Comment: @Jaime I get an error as xi and Z are not the same lengths. is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You're using it a bit wrong.  `interp = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(X,Y,Z,kind='cubic'); new_zi = interp(xi, yi)`  (At least I think that is what @Jaime is suggesting)

Comment: @EthanCoon I think `interp2d` requires a rectangular grid, which you would build by first calling `griddata` on  `X, Y, Z`.

Comment: `interp2d` doesn't require a rectangular grid, but is less robust than `griddata`.

Comment: @Jaime @Ethan Coon - I have made an edit with your suggested solutions however they haven't worked and I have posted the error message. Reducing the number of xi and yi values makes zi = `<scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp2d at 0x414cdd0>`

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

`s` is the parameter which sets the error from the given points (that is how far the interpolated surface can miss the source points by). If `s=0`, then the interpolation must hit every point exactly.  If there is noise in your data, the higher derivatives will not be smooth which it turn will 1) make your fitted surface look awful as it contorts itself to mach the values *and* the higher derivatives 2) require *alot* of control points.

For noisy data, higher order interpolation can actually be much worse than linear interpolation.

According to the `interp2D` documentation it is really just calling `bisplrep` ([doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplrep)), which you can work with directly, and gives you access to a lot more knobs.

To get 'smother' interpolation, you are going to have to accept some degree of smoothing of your original data.  If that is ok or not is up to you.